# Removing rows in matrix when having required fields with Safecracker forms

Tags: matrix

I have multiple matrix fields in the multiple channels.  In most channels the fields (columns) are not required.  In these cases removing rows means making sure all fields for the row are emptied.

I do have matrix field however that have required fields (columns).  I can't seem to find any way to remove a row completely.  I would have expected a '-' button, similar to the '+' button, but there is none.

I can hardly believe this functionality is missing, so I must be missing something

Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hover over the number at the start of the matrix row and click on the downward arrow that appears. You'll then get the option to delete row.  It's subtle, but it's there. :)

Comment: It's very subtle, even hard to find :-)

Comment: Any idea where to find it on safecracker forms?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize you were using it with Safecracker. I've not used Matrix on the front end myself yet, so I'm not certain if it's there or not. I would have thought so though.  If you run Firebug are you getting any JS errors?

Answer (score 0):

The normal functionality available in the CP (as Jean St-Amand pointed out above) is actually available in the same way on the SafeCracker forms.  In my case I had loaded my own jQuery which is not compatible with the jQuery needs of Matrix/Safecracker.  If I use the one included with SafeCracker all is well!

T